# Jquery $.each loop counter

Tags: jquery

i am running this code when data is typed in a text input:

```
$("input#search").live("keyup", function(e) {       
        var search_string = $(this).val();
        var i = 0;
        var trHTML = '';
        if(search_string !== '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/section/search_go",
                data: { query: search_string },
                cache: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    $.each(response, function(i, item) {


                        trHTML += '<tr>';
                        trHTML += '<td>' + item.accountnumber + '</td>';
                        trHTML += '<td>' + item.company + '</td>';
                        trHTML += '<td>' + item.phone + '</td>';
                        trHTML += '<td>' + item.postcode + '</td>';
                        trHTML += '</tr>';
                    });
                    $('#customers').html(trHTML);
                }
            });
            console.log(i);
        }

        /*if(counter === 0 || search_string == '') {
            $('#customers').html('<tr><td colspan="4">No Results</td></tr>');
        }*/
    });
```

i am trying to get the number of records in the `$.each` loop but i cannot seem to do that.

i have tried using `i` which is in the function and i also tried adding a `counter` variable and for each loop i added `counter++` but that still isnt working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope if you need to get number of times loops run,

Simply do `response.length`. both will be same.

```
$("input#search").live("keyup", function(e) {       
        var search_string = $(this).val();
        var resultLength;   //Declare variable
        var i = 0;
        var trHTML = '';
        if(search_string !== '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/section/search_go",
                data: { query: search_string },
                cache: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    resultLength = response.length;  //assign the length
                    $.each(response, function(i, item) {


                        trHTML += '<tr>';
                        trHTML += '<td>' + item.accountnumber + '</td>';
                        trHTML += '<td>' + item.company + '</td>';
                        trHTML += '<td>' + item.phone + '</td>';
                        trHTML += '<td>' + item.postcode + '</td>';
                        trHTML += '</tr>';
                    });
                    $('#customers').html(trHTML);
                }
            });
            console.log(i);
        }

        /*if(resultLength === 0 || search_string == '') {  //access here
            $('#customers').html('<tr><td colspan="4">No Results</td></tr>');
        }*/
    });
```

Comment: DO u have any specific scenario to calculate using counter

Comment: tried replacing my `console.log(i)` with `console.log(response.log)` but i get `Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined`

Comment: in javascript variables are block scoped, so it is not possible to access response out of success block,

Comment: what you need excatly??

Comment: i need the number of records returned from the ajax post - so the number of loops

Comment: how can i run that code at the bottom that says if the `resultLength` is 0

Comment: @charlie You need to declare `var resultLength` at the top like @RajaSekar did, then set its value to `response.length` inside the success function. Once you've done that you'll be able to access it anywhere inside the function, but you also have to remember that `$.ajax()` is **asynchronous**, which means that your `.success()` function won't run until *after* the `console.log()` and the `if(resultLength...)` block where you have them. That's the main problem. Any code that needs to run *after* the `$.ajax()` call must be triggered from the `.success()` function.

Answer (score 0):

console.log(i) must be inside of each function.

```
success: function(response) {
                $.each(response, function(i, item) {


                    trHTML += '<tr>';
                    trHTML += '<td>' + item.accountnumber + '</td>';
                    trHTML += '<td>' + item.company + '</td>';
                    trHTML += '<td>' + item.phone + '</td>';
                    trHTML += '<td>' + item.postcode + '</td>';
                    trHTML += '</tr>';
                    console.log(i);  // this "i" from here function(i, item)
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your approach is that `$.ajax()` calls are **asynchronous**[1]. This is a very important part of web development: AJAX requests (and HTTP requests in general) can take a long time (occasionally on the order of 30 seconds or longer), and if your JavaScript code is blocked waiting for it to finish, the whole browser will lock up. (See the linked MDN article article for more details on this.)

What this means for you is that any code that relies on the results from your `$.ajax()` request *must* be triggered from within the `success` callback function that gets run when the HTTP  request returns data successfully.

Another comment on your code, unrelated to your question: you're currently making an HTTP request on every single `keyup` event. This is going to *really* slow down your page, it can overload your server, and it can cause race conditions and other sorts of bugs if things don't go perfectly (remember that HTTP is somewhat unpredictable). You should debounce your `keyup` event handler. Use something like Ben Alman's jQuery throttle/debounce plugin [2] to debounce your handler (see example below). (You might want to change it to a `keypress` event too, though that's not as necessary; the `keypress` event object just includes some extra info that can sometimes be helpful.)

I would recommend something like this (assuming you've included some jQuery plugin to give you `$.debounce()`):

```
$("input#search").live(
    "keypress", // changed keyup to keypress; not necessary, but often preferred
    $.debounce(
        250,    // debounced by 250ms; might want longer, but I wouldn't go any less
        function(e) {
            var search_string = $(this).val(),
                no_results_str = '<tr><td colspan="4">No Results</td></tr>';
            if (search_string === '') {
                $('#customers').html(no_results_str);
            }
            else {
                if(search_string !== '') {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "/section/search_go",
                        data: { query: search_string },
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(response) {
                            console.log('Got '+response.length+' results');
                            if(response.length === 0) {
                                $('#customers').html(no_results_str);
                            }
                            else {
                                var trHTML = '';
                                $.each(response, function(i, item) {

                                    trHTML += '<tr>';
                                    trHTML += '<td>' + item.accountnumber + '</td>';
                                    trHTML += '<td>' + item.company + '</td>';
                                    trHTML += '<td>' + item.phone + '</td>';
                                    trHTML += '<td>' + item.postcode + '</td>';
                                    trHTML += '</tr>';
                                });
                                $('#customers').html(trHTML);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    )
);
```

**Links:**

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests
2. http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/